# Christmas List / Catalog

Tags: spacing, graphics, lists

I'm fairly new to LaTeX, and I thought a fun project would be to create a Christmas list that looks like a shopping catalog.  Something like this:

[image: christmas catalog]

How would I go about this?  Any good templates or examples would be appreciated!

Comment: To be honest, I'd rather use Illustrator, CorelDraw or Scribus for this, as this is a rather graphical job. If you want to do it with LaTeX have a look at the `textpos` or `eso-pic` packages.

Comment: You could place boxes with TikZ, but i agree with @uwe, a more graphical tool will be more helpful.

Comment: This is not “typography”. While TeX might do it, it excels in other applications.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

LaTeX is *so* not designed for this kind of document. But if you must, must.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\setlength\unitlength{1cm}
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent
\begin{picture}(0,0)\bfseries\large
\put(4,3){\includegraphics{house}}
\put(0.5,5){\parbox{5cm}{\raggedright
If you are feeling generous 
I'd like a house, preferably one with architectural
design integrity, like this}}

\put(0,17){\includegraphics{car}}
\put(8,21.5){\parbox{3cm}{\raggedright
I'd like a \textbf{Car},
preferably with four wheels.}}

\put(0,10){\includegraphics{computer}}
\put(0,9){\parbox{6cm}{\raggedright
A new \textbf{computer}
would be nice. (I won't need vim)}}

\put(8,12){\includegraphics{cake}}
\put(9,11.5){\parbox{3cm}{\raggedright
\textbf{Cake}, of course}}


\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may have started one of our own [Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/168244).

Comment: @Werner: that's it. We are officialy in. `:)`

Comment: ... "a car preferably with four wheels" :) hopefully