# How to place several images on top of each other and center them on the page?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, geometry

I can't figure out how to center the images. The aim is to center the images and make them large enough to stretch over the cropping line.

Optionally: Is it possible to control how close the images are (in other words how big is the gap between the bottom border of one image and the top border of another image).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extbook}
% ############################## geometry
\usepackage%[showframe]
           {geometry}
\geometry
  { hmarginratio =  1:1
  , vmarginratio = 1:1
  , bindingoffset = 0cm
  , onecolumn
  , a4paper
  , layoutwidth = 50 mm
  , layoutheight = 180 mm
  , layouthoffset=\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\csname Gm@layoutwidth\endcsname)/2\relax
   , layoutvoffset=\dimexpr(\paperheight-\csname Gm@layoutheight\endcsname)/2\relax
  , showcrop
  }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% ############################### Document
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\noindent\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\noindent\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\noindent\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\noindent\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\noindent\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why all those minipages? I can't see the use. Try putting `\vfill` between the images.

Comment: Add package (not option) `showframe` additionally to `geometry`.

Comment: you do not want `minipage` or `figure` here, just `\includegraphics` and possibly some spacing commands.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213286/christmas-list-catalog/213293#213293  for explicit control over position of images and text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement of the problem is not very clear, but perhaps this is what you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extbook}

% ############################## geometry
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  hmarginratio =  1:1,
  vmarginratio = 1:1,
  bindingoffset = 0cm,
  onecolumn,
  a4paper,
  layoutwidth = 50 mm,
  layoutheight = 180 mm,
  layouthoffset=\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\csname Gm@layoutwidth\endcsname)/2\relax,
  layoutvoffset=\dimexpr(\paperheight-\csname Gm@layoutheight\endcsname)/2\relax,
  showcrop
}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% ############################### Document

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

{\parindent=0pt
 \newcommand{\shiftleft}{\hspace*{-0.5\dimexpr\csname Gm@layoutwidth\endcsname-\textwidth\relax}}

\shiftleft\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}\shiftleft\vfill

\shiftleft\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}\shiftleft\vfill

\shiftleft\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}\shiftleft

}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! How can I control the vertical position? (the gap between them). I want to place all 5 images close to each other. This is meant to be bookmark :)

Comment: @chejnik Put `\vspace*{\fill}` at the top and at the bottom, and `\vspace{<whatever}` between the images.

Comment: Thank you, I am using `\vspace` and I have added also command to shift it up `\newcommand{\shiftup}{\vspace*{-0.15\dimexpr\csname Gm@layoutheight\endcsname-\textwidth\relax}}` (regards to your code).