# How can I use command \put and text with it

Tags: macros, input, text

How can I justify the text to the margins I want?

```
\put(55.91998,-499.32){\fontsize{12}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}vehicula tincidunt ipsum, at faucibus velit ornare euismod. Aenean fermentum neque eget}
```

I need this text to have the same length of others and that I can define the length.

Tks im noob.

Comment: you can place it in a `\parbox` of the desired width, but why `fontsize{12}{1}` ? 12pt font on baselines that are 1pt apart is not a usual specification.  You should almost never need to use `\fontsize` or `\usefont`  outside font packages.

Comment: see examples of parbox in `put` here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213286/christmas-list-catalog/213293#213293

Comment: Thanks from the heart tanks. used and it worked now i just need the text to be justified so it starts and ends in same place soorry for asking but realy need help \put(55.91998,-550.32){\parbox{16cm}{\raggedright Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ut tincidunt lorem. Vivamus vehicula tincidunt ipsum, at faucibus velit ornare euismod. Aenean fermentum neque eget lacinia vehicula. In et eros fringilla, euismod lorem eu, tempor lectus. Fusce consequat, tortor porta lacinia consectetur, purus lacus maximus massa, in tristique sem enim cursus tortor. Pellentesque mollis or