# Placing equations and sentences at specific coordinates

Tags: floats, equations, document-classes

would like to create a document.

On each page of the document, I would like to have three things:

a) a few math equations (and a few short sentences) at very specific locations and with a specific font size

b) a few horizontal and vertical lines at very specific locations and with specific lengths and thicknesses,

and c) one or two inserted figures at specific locations and with a specific size.

Please, is there a document class that would allow me to do such a thing:  pick SPECIFIC coordinates on a page (x cm horizontally from a reference corner, y cm vertically from the same reference corner) and insert an equation or a phrase or a figure that starts EXACTLY at these coordinates?

I have not used latex in over 10 years and I am very rusty. I would appreciate any/all relevant comments.

Also, first time posting. I hope my question is appropriate.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Probably with Ti*k*Z and the current page coordinates: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89588/positioning-relative-to-page-in-tikz (although "exactly start" is not clear to me: do you mean the top left corner of the box? the baseline?)

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213293/1090

Comment: See also the tikzpagenodes package for (current page text area).